# Filter request URL before any processing in CQ5.6

Tags: aem, sling

In my CQ5.6 application,. as soon as the user hits a URL, I need to edit it using a certain parameters. All this must happen before Sling starts processing the URL.

I basically need to convert the URL like:
`www.mysite.fr` --> converts to --> `/content/mysite/fr/`

and so on....

I understand I'll need to create an OSGi bundle for this, but which API should I use to ensure that the URL is filtered by my class first and then catered by 
Sling. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want a code-based solution for multiple websites (and you don't want to manage /etc/map) you can setup your own Filter:

```
package your.package;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;

@Component(immediate=true, enabled=true)
@Service(value=Filter.class)
@Properties({
    @Property(name="sling.filter.scope", value="REQUEST", propertyPrivate=true),
    @Property(name="service.ranking", intValue=-10000, propertyPrivate=true)
})
public class YourFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductSEOFilter.class);

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctx) throws Exception {
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() throws Exception {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
        String lang = "en";

        // 1. get domain and path
        // 2. check if your conditions are met
        // 3. extract language from domain
        // 4. internal redirect

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/mysite/" + lang);
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

you don't need to bother checking for and passing querystrings--those are carried on in the dispatcher. it only needs a new url to forward to.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via **Sling URL Mapping** without the need for a filter. The simpliest way to achieve this is to create a node under the `/etc/map` directory with a resource type of `sling:Mapping` & called `www.mysite.fr`.

This then takes a property of `sling:internalRedirect` — if an incoming request matches the node name, this property is appended to the path to continue with internal resource resolution.

```
<map>
    <http jcr:primaryType="sling:OrderedFolder">
        <www.mysite.fr 
            jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
            sling:internalRedirect="/content/mysite/fr"/>
    </http>
</map>
```

The above will ensure any request coming to `www.mysite.fr` is resolved to `www.mysite.fr/content/mysite/fr`.

You can also pattern matching based on regex properties rather than names & include port numbers or schemes too. The full documentation is available [on the Sling website](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have an issue with /etc/map  1) it doesn't seem to work in CQ5.6.1 and 2) the application is to be sued by multiple websites. So, I need some code-based solution that can be controlled and as isolated as possible.

Comment: Hi Riju, what do you mean that it doesn't seem to work in 5.6.1? Can you isolate the error to anything in particular (e.g. if you test via the Sling Resource Resolver tab of Felix)?